# Width of inner div only as wide as visible part of outerdiv?

Tags: html, width, css

I have an outer div with a fixed with (and scroll bar horizontally). Within this outer div I have two divs under each other: one is set to be bigger than the outer div (thus activating the outer div its scroll bar), and one is set to be 100%.

The second inner div (the 100% width), is only as wide as the outer div is visible. If you scroll to the left, the div stops and is very much not 100% of the outer div.

```
.parent{
     white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:scroll;
    width:200px;
    } 

.holder {
    width: 500px;
    background: url(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif); } 

.holder1 {
    width: inherit;
    background: blue; } 

.holder> div{
   display:inline-block;
   white-space:normal;
   background:red;
}​


<div class="parent">
    <div class="holder">
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="holder1">
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

I have an JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EUtLh/16/

to make it more clear. Is there any way I can get the second div to be as wide as the first div, without giving it a fixed width? The first div is made dynamically and it's width determines the width of the outer div.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In this case, can't you work with % values, the inner div being like 30% of the outer (100%) div?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean. The inner div with with class holder1 needs to be as wide as the entire div, including scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the two holder divs in a "wrapper" div whose width is determined dynamicly (as holder was before).  Change the holder widths to 100% and they will be as wide as the "containing" div's width.

```
<div class="parent">

 *<div class="wrapper">*

  <div class="holder">
      <div>1</div>
  </div><br>
  <div class="holder1">
     <div>1</div>
  </div>

 *</div>*

</div>

CSS:
.wrapper {
   width:500px;
}
.holder {
   width: 100%;
   background: url(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif);
}
.holder1 {
   width: 100%;
   background: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EUtLh/29/

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to use the javascript (give a try with Jquery)

```
$('.holder1').width($('.holder').width());​
```

this might help I guess

Comment: Thank you for your reaction. I had thought of that, but I was actually looking for something without javascript, since the innerdivs will be filled with other divs based on database queries, creating some sort of a timeline (the further the innerinnerinnerdivs are to the left, the further it is in time).

Answer (score 0):

Giving your divs one common class and two seperate id's is one solution:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="holderClass" id="holder">
         <div>1</div>
    </div><br>
    <div class="holderClass" id="holder1">
         <div>2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
.parent{
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:scroll;
    width:200px;
    }
.holderClass {
    width: 500px;
}
#holder{
    background: url(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif);
}
#holder1 {
    background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you reaction, but as I mentioned is the first innerdiv dynamically build, and it's width isn't fixed. It contains a lot of small divs next to each other, but the amount of small divs is based on somethings else. Therefore, it is not possible to give both the same (fixed) width.